# How to free a dynamic array of CString?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, mfc

I have a dynamic array of `CString` in my class, I used `new` operator in constructor of my class to create that, so I wrote one line in destructor to free the memory. It doesn't cause any error but it leads to a breakpoint in runtime!
Error is :
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Genetic Algorithm.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Genetic Algorithm.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Genetic Algorithm.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

and the code is:

```
//in constructor
StringFormat = new CString[Info.VariablesCount + 1];
for (int i=0;i<=Info.VariablesCount;i++)
     StringFormat[i] = "%2.3f";`

// in destructor
free(StringFormat);
```

Notice that `StringFormat*` is a private member of class, I have some other dynamic arrays in this class too, but I can free them easily with free method, this problem is just with `CString` dynamic arrays, so what am I missing?

Comment: Why not use some "dynamic array class" like std::vector or even, since you want an array of CStrings, CStringArray?

Comment: I didn't know there are such things in MFC! I'll take a look at them. thanks

Comment: std::vector is a standard C++ thing, and since MFC is C++, you have it there. CStringArray, and other containers, are part of MFC. But I would recommend using the standard ones. They work well with MFC classes like CString and are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from deleting the string using `delete[] StringFormat` you need to follow the rule of three

- Provide a copy constructor
- provide an assignment overload function

check [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/).

Answer (score 2):

You used `new[]` to allocate the `CString` array.  You have to use `delete[]` to free it - Basic C++ memory rules.

In your destructor use: `delete[] StringFormat;`

Answer (score 1):

You have used `new` operator to allocate memory, and attempting to release the memory using `free`. Both have different heaps, other than some semantics they differ. You allocate using `new`, release memory using `delete`. Similarly, you allocate using `malloc` and release the same using `free`. You cannot mix them!

Also, as mentioned by others, if you use array-mode `new` (and not scaler `new`), you must delete it using array-mode `delete` and not scalar `delete` (i.e. `delete[]`, and not `delete`).

It is very much recommended that you use `vector`, `list`, `CArray`, `CStringArray` or some other container to have array-of-strings, rather than managing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for editing my question. and thanks for your answer, but as I asked from everyone, why that worked with other types of variables!? I created a two  dimentional array of double with new operator and I released it with free without any problem!This breakpoint just happened when it was a CString array! why?

Comment: If you run that kind of code under debugger (a debug build), you would for sure get an assertion! Try with newest version of Visual Studio you have.

Comment: Saman, with simple built in types like "int", it generally doesn't cause problems because constructors and destructors don't have to get called.